# Does a HTML page need to be wellformed?

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a website with friends.
I'm coding the server program and my HTML/CSS knowledge is low.

I received from the guy whose job is the HTML/CSS stuff a page which had a section which looked like this:

```
<div>
    <form>
</div>
    </form>
```

This is as far as I know (I noticed when I tried to inherit it) not well formed.

after googling around I just figured out that non well formed HTML won't even show up.

So I asked him about the `<div>` thing and he just said rude "The page looks as we want it to look, doesn't it?!"

And he is right, it does.

But now I'm asking my self (I'm a bit cowardly as I know as a Highlevel language coder as I'm, disrespect a standard leads into undefined behaving)
will the look of, what he calls "It does what we want" be interpreted by each browser the same? Or even I'm wrong and this is allowed because of some css stuff?

Or is he just that kind of coder who tries around, and it is luck, that it looks like we want, he doesn't even know why it does so?

And maybe some browsers we don't know won't even show up the page?

Sorry for my bad question style, but I don't really know how to ask the question, as I'm not really in HTML/CSS.

Comment: Many things depend on the HTML to be less ill-formed than that. This kind of HTML will lead to problems and I'm surprised you didn't get any with css or js yet.

Comment: `Does a HTML page need to be wellformed?` - In short yes. Mismatched tags, and closing elements inside other elements will lead to problems.

Comment: Ok, so I have reasons to advise him to restructure it anyway. but I would like to know why the page looks as we want it to look nevertheless

Comment: Does it look different in different browsers ?

Comment: Modern browsers have robust parsing algorithms. An example of such an algorithm is HTML Tidy, http://tidy.sourceforge.net/. Anyway, another simple reason to fix this markup, would be, that you could never gain a "valid 3C Markup" badge (http://validator.w3.org/). Although it's not worth much.

Comment: It might look *right* because the browser interprets the closing elements differently, and knows you meant to close them in the right place. It should be *valid* `HTML`

Comment: i think that most browsers - especially at firefox - adds an end tag automatically when there should be one during the parsing and then ignoring other "strange" end tags.

Comment: It is bad, and even if this particular instance doesn't cause problem, having a developer who doesn't care about these things *will* cause problems as some point. Get him to fix it, if he is unable then I would say he isn't good enough for the role

Comment: There are too many questions, and they are too vague, for SO format. E.g., the question in the title just raises the question “in which sense?”.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I disagree. The question in the title is very clear, and so is the answer.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela Well I don't think its too vague, as its a simple "yes"/"no" question and the post is just explaining my situation.

Comment: The question in the title is different from all the questions in the body, and it entirely depends on the definition of “need”.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that having well formed HTML documents makes it easier for the page to be indexed by search engines and also makes it easier for screen readers.

Comment: HTML is a description of a document structure, it is not a magically-do-what-I-mean technology. Your friend can't simply throw random tags into a soup and expect the outcome to always be what he expects. Yes, it may work in this instance, but when are you going to draw the line and finally actually stick to the standard? Something will not accidentally happen to work one day... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your friend (who you should stop calling a coder, he isn't) is wrong.

On a practical, down-to-Earth, level, in this specific case, the browsers end the form when they see the `</div>` end tag. So if you have

```
<div>
    <form>
</div>
   <input name="what">
    </form>
```

the input will not be submitted with the form.

And this is one case where the latest browsers all agree on how to act, but in general, different browsers respond differently to errors. (I have compiled some examples of that on my own website, [here](http://examples.strictquirks.nl/errors/).)

So your friend may be satisfied with the site working in one particular browser, but he'll be out of luck when the browser updates to a new version. Not to mention other browsers.

As a high level coder, would you deliver an application that compiles, but with warnings?

PS: you said "I just figured out that non well formed HTML won't even show up." but that is a misunderstanding. Most browsers throw an error when they encounter non-well-formed XHTML, but in the case of HTML, they show as much as they can and work very hard on recovering from errors. Still, different browsers use different error-recovery algorithms, so you really really shouldn't count on that.

Comment: Of course I won't! (As many others do...) Exactl thats the reason why his "It is working" didn't satisfy me. and your reason sounds simple to me. (I just started translating the HTML into my own styl language when I saw this. So I wasn't even able to check the input is getting received or not right now.) Exactly thats our case. And he just cared about the look probbably.

Comment: In the question, there is no tag between `</div>` and `</form>`, so this answer speculates on what might happen in *other* situations and suggests general principles, without specifying the *need* for valid markup in the case presented.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela True. The OP said it "looks as we want it to look" though, so I assumed there was some content, otherwise you wouldn't see anything. Also, there is the mistaken remark about well-formed HTML not showing up, but I better edit that into the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer. Some browsers are forgiving of badly formed html ... but sometimes in different ways. Some issues you may come up against:

- CSS styling acts differently across browsers
- You may trigger Quirks mode
- Manipulating items with JavaScript may give unexpected results...etc

Good luck.

Comment: No luck is needed. As I know now, this isn't allowed, it will be changed. And I don't care who does this. so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer depends upon your target user** who are going to view your UI....many websites target a particular browser and design according to them, but, in most cases, a website is open to world wide web

All the browser render the HTML and CSS differently,so, in order to make your site have a same look and feel across the browsers, irrespective of browser-type and its version, you have to follow a well-formed approach

apart from a well-formed HTML markup, you need to have *vendor prefixes* for cross browser css attributes...general ones used are :

- -moz
- -webkit
- -ms

**but** if you are targeting a particular web-browser like IEv9 the you can just follow a spec according to the browser render capability of this browser and ignore the view rendered in other browsers